# Getting exception while running test case in appium

Tags: appium

I am a newbie to Appium, recently i am trying to run my first appium test case, but getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session.
```

I am using `appium server 1.6.3` on `localhost`, and also i am using `selenium server 3.4.0` and appium java client version `java-client-5.0.0-BETA7.`

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Several notes:

- avoid using `beta` builds when you start with new open-source tool
- Appium already includes [specific selenium version](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/build.gradle#L53), so by setting it yourself you may get incompatibility issue.

Try with appium stable appium server **v1.7.2** and java client **v5.0.4**